# spring chaining constructor with service injection

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I having a class, like this

```
public class testClass {
    private TestService testService;

    public testClass() {
        this(testService);
    }

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public testClass(TestService testService) {
        this.testService = testService;
    }
}
```

where the default no-argument constructor is mandatory, 'cause I having a structured factory design, from there I am calling my no-argument constructor so I don't want to changes this structure. So I went with `chaining constructor` to call `argumented constructor` from `default constructor`. But java is throwing the exception

`cannot reference testService before supertype constructor has been called`,

I can solve this exception by having `testService` as `static`, but from [here](http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=105), I red that having static injection is not always a good idea.

Can some one advice me with some design solution on how can solve or call this `argumented constructor` from `default constructor` without having static injection.

Comment: What do you think `this(testService);` should do? Why do you think so? What does a constructor do? What should be the value of `testService` at that line? Why do you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis My understanding is, when I calling default construtor I will getting an instance of `testClass` injected with `testService`

Comment: What is this supposed to be: "structured factory design"

Comment: This is literally just supposed to be `@Autowired private TestService testService;`

Comment: @JensSchauder, I am following `factory design pattern` to call this class, like `new testClass()`

Comment: If Spring is using your parameterless constructor, where is it going to inject anything?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, so you saying that there is no need for chaining constructors

Comment: Right. Do what @EpicPandaForce suggested, annotate your field and get rid of your parameterized constructor.

Comment: Ok, let me try, but my unit test showing the `testService` as null

Comment: You need to set up the autowiring context in unit tests, although I don't remember how to do that. There must be a guide for it.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, we doing that, using `@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:testContext.xml")`

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

**Field injection**

Add an @Autowired annotation to the field and throw away the constructor with arguments.

Spring will inject the dependency using reflection. If as in your example the default constructor after that is empty and the only constructor you can throw it away too, because the java compiler will create it for you.

Pro: short code

**Constructor Injection**
Throw away the parameterless constructor. Spring will provide the dependency just fine.

Pro: your code works fine without Spring which is great, among other things for tests. [Here is a more detailed explanation why I prefer this variation](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2012/01/01/the-one-correct-way-to-do-dependency-injection/).

Some additional comment:

- Always name Classes with first letter upper case. Everything else makes your code really confusing to read for Java developers.
- You don't have a factory there at all. There are various ways to use Factories with Spring, look it up if you are interested.

Comment: I getting my injected service as null, ok let me try

Comment: @Suganthan In that case we need more information about the test you are using to test this.

Comment: Yes, I need to check if I having any issue with my test

Comment: I checked it not the issue with test, it the issue with code as said, service is still null. its fine.